# Farewell dinner: only drinks covered

Tags: professionalism, farewell

I'm leaving my company and I was wondering if it's okay to plan a final dinner with my colleagues and friends and their families, specifying that I will be paying for the drinks (with the implication being that food will be covered by them), or does this come off as tacky?

Comment: In my experience, when someone does a farewell dinner or happy hour, the colleagues are usually the ones buying *you* the drinks. Every work culture is different!

Comment: I have rather heard from it being handled the other way round: food was covered, drinks everyone payed for themselves.

Comment: Sounds kinda tacky to me.

Comment: Your workplace/country culture will play a huge part in this. I've only ever seen it where people go to a place for food and all pay for themselves. Then they move on to a nearby pub/bar where the departing colleague may (but is in no way obliged to) offer to buy the first round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it depends on what your friends and their families are like.

If they're going to abuse the "free booze" offer and get blind drunk on your money, how are you going to feel about it?

You could temper this by buying the first round, or a couple of bottles of wine per table, and then allow them to buy you drinks...

Comment: I think the idea of offering the first round is a nice approach. You invite everyone, and are very clear on what they can expect

Answer (score 7):

Where I come from, it's generally the other way round: if someone invites people and does not want to pay the whole bill (company events for example often are this way), it's food is paid for, drinks is everybody's own responsibility.

What's nice about that is that food can be calculated more easily in advance and will be evenly distributed, while drinks are highly volatile. For example everybody will have one meal ranging from maybe 15-20€, but some people will have a glass of water for 3€ because they travel by car and others will have 4 cocktails for 100€. So you invite all people for about the same sum per person, and yet everybody can drink what s/he wants to.

Generally speaking, follow what your culture deems best.

Comment: **4 cocktails for 100€** - Ouch

Comment: @JohnHC There are actually cocktails that contain actual diamonds and actual gold. Seriously.  So the sky's the limit on price.

Comment: @JohnHC try a bog standard thin pizza in Norway for 35 USD :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than funding "dinner", go to happy hour.  If you have to spring for appetizers, that's not cheap-ish, and if anyone wants entrees instead then they can foot the bill for those.  Make sure you SPECIFICALLY make the offer for only drinks and appetizers.  Some will want alcohol, and others will not -- don't worry about that part.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with that approach is you are kind of encouraging drinking.  Some people don't drink.

A common approach for when someone wants to pitch you a product or service
is a limited menu with salad, entree, and desert. You get beef, chicken, or vegetarian. If you just open the menu you take a chance that someone abuses it just like they might abuse an open bar.

Answer (score 0):

> or does this come off as tacky?

Yes, it comes off as tacky. Don't invite people to dinner if you're not prepared to pay for their food.

Comment: Good to know, however I didn't use the word "invite" but rather "plan" in my question.